# Alternative to a singleton implementation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I'm working on an app which has a ContentManager class.  This class migrates files from the bundle, and performs other checks when the app is first opened.  It's next used in a ViewController at the end of a rather long chain of ViewControllers.  As far as I can tell, there are two methods of implementing this:

1. Instantiate the class in the first ViewController, and pass it through the segues to the final ViewController.
2. Create a singleton sharedInstance in the first ViewController and access it where needed using that sharedInstance.

It seems a lot cleaner and simpler to create the singleton.  However, I've read a lot about how singletons are bad.  I'm wondering if I'm missing some alternative way of doing this without using a singleton or messily passing the instance through all the view controllers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This seems to be more of an opinion question than a programming question. What are the specific reasons that you believe singletons to be "bad"? Your `ContentManager` class sounds like an ideal candidate for a singleton since you will never have more than one instance of it in your app.

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you for your quick reply.  I've read that it's bad to hide dependencies and it's the equivalent of a global variable etc.  I'm glad to hear it doesn't sound like a problem to have it as a singleton, really I was worried that perhaps using it was a symptom of poor coding or something

Comment: Swift leans much more towards functional language where global scope is not a dirty word. I have seen many examples of lasagne code, because someone is trying to be academically correct and therefore avoids singleton. Your case seams to be a good case for singleton and you should not feel ashamed :)

Comment: Thank you Georg, I'll stick with the singleton now I know it's not a sin :)